# MYSQL : error 1045 (28000).

Tags: mysql

This is my first time dealing with MySQL tables. I am taking a Linux system admin class in my college and I encountered a problem while following the lab.

When I do this command:
     **GRANT ALL ON alpha.* TO dbuser@10.10.0.6 IDENTIFIED BY 'CSCI480';**

and later do:
     **mysql -udbuser -p -h 10.10.0.6**

I get access denied message.

I would like to know what exactly is going on, why do I get those message. By the way, I am just following my Professor's Lab guide.

[Followed lab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wy7MP.png)

Comment: With mysql you need `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` after changing privileges. Also, mysql is quite picky about user/hostmasks, you might want to say `... TO 'dbuser'@'10.10.0.6' ...`. Does that help?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately, those things didn't resolve the error ;( . But one weird thing is . who is 'dbuser', I don't remember creating a user...

Comment: Is 10.10.0.6 the localhost? Or a different machine?

Comment: The Grant command creates the user dbuser if they do not exist.

Comment: 10.10.0.6 is the server I am using to create MySQL tables...so it's consider local host I believe.

Comment: This is how I do it, works every time: `CREATE DATABASE foo; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON foo.* TO 'someuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'somepass'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`. This assumes of course the db runs on, and is accessed from, localhost. In your case, you should use the IP *from the host you use to connect to the database*.

Comment: You do not need to flush privileges after a GRANT statement.

Comment: Please see the addition to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's on the localhost, just use:

```
GRANT ALL ON alpha.* TO dbuser@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'CSCI480';
```

and

```
mysql -u dbuser -p
```

**Edit:**

I noticed you stated the error says "using password: NO". After the above command press Enter and it will ask you for a password, type: CSCI480. Is it prompting you for a password? What if you try:

```
mysql -u dbuser -pCSCI480
```

Comment: ERROR 1045 (28000): ACCESS denied for user 'dbuser'@'localhost' (using password: NO ) is the message

Comment: does it have to do with running mysql with "mysql -uroot" ?

Comment: Depending of course on your version of linux, you should probably be running mysql as "sudo service mysql start"

Comment: If you log in as root can you verify that you see the user in the users table? "use mysql; select host, user, password from user;"

Comment: You stated that it says "using password: NO". Are you sure you are typing a password at the prompt? You should be using CSCI480.

Comment: It is working now. Under password field, I should've entered CSCI480...the problem was that I left it empty and just hit enter. Thank you very much :D